# Using LinqBridge in .Net2.0 Website

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, linqbridge

has anyone been able to use Linqbridge on a .Net 2.0 Website?
I have no problem using it in a normal .Net 2.0 console, but when I use the methods in the website, 
I get

```
Feature 'extension method' cannot be used because it is not part of the ISO-2 C# language specification
```

Comment: *Where* in the website? code-behind? aspx? something else?

Comment: @Mauricio, when you create a new project, there is an option to choose new website. Use that. Just a newly created website with no codes will do too. Add in LinqBridge as reference and do some calling with Linq, it will reproduce the same error as I get

Comment: @C_Rance: weird, I'd expect something like that to happen in an aspx... but not on compiled code. Is that a compile-time error or runtime error?

Comment: @Mauricio: luckily its compile time, so after I compile the website, all the errors start showing. In terms of intellisense, it worked fine, problem shows when you build it or assign it to variables

Comment: what version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: using VS 2010, so I believe this would actually be a better option. Correct me if im wrong

Answer (score 2):

I think the error message is pretty clear. Extension methods aren't supported in 2.0. If you want to use an extension method in 2.0, you'd need to modify it by removing the `this` and call it explicitly.

If you had:

```
public static class ExtensionMethods {
    public static bool IsOdd(this int x) {
        return x % 2 != 0;
    }
}
```

Then `ExtensionMethods` and code like `number.IsOdd()` won't compile.

You'd need to remove the `this` in the `IsOdd` method signature and call it as `ExtensionMethods.IsOdd(number)` to get it to work under 2.0.

If I recall correctly, that's the approach the authors of LinqBridge used.

Hope that helps.

Comment: so u mean I have to use the code file and manually edit their method signature?

Comment: Yes. I suspect that the extension method exists in some copied code from somewhere else. It should not be in the LinqBridge code, since it's written for .NET 2.0.

Comment: I edited the .cs file, and tried to remove all the this, but it give me some other compiler issue. Guess some of the methods they use will still require "this". Any idea how to remove the ISO standard instead? A normal console application is working fine, but not a website. Voted u up for trying to help

Comment: Thank you for the upvote. I'm not sure what ISO standard would apply to this situation.

Would you happen to have a reference to the System.Core 3.5 DLL instead of the 2.0 one?

Comment: U're welcome. I have not tried referencing a 3.5 DLL but I believe after referencing, I do not even require LinqBridge, as Linq is dependent on this reference if Im not wrong. The problem is that my user's standard requires .Net 2.0, I've more experience with LINQ so ended up wasted alot of time using 2.0 as Im not as familar

Comment: True, if you can reference System.Core 3.5, then you can just use LINQ. But if you reference the 3.5 DLL and compile as 2.0, you might see errors like this. You'll want to look at DLLs referenced in the web.config also, since it's only happening on the web site.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're confusing .NET and C# versions. LINQBridge supports .NET 2.0, but you still need C# 3.0 or later (i.e. VS2008 or later) to compile code with extension method or LINQ syntax sugar. Once compiled, the assembly runs without issue on .NET 2.0 runtimes. That's the benefit of LINQBridge.

Comment: actually if that's the case, I will already have no problem. The 1st try that I did was to download the LinqBridge dll from their site and add reference to it. Like I mention, I have tested on a .Net 2.0 console application and it is working fine. But doing the same way on a website project fails me. So the dll download from linqbridge does include the extension method